# What is the simplest function to generate this curve shape?

Tags: functions, soft-question

I'm looking for the most straightforward function that generates this shape:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4Rz.png]

The best I've found so far is: $\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{\alpha})^\beta}$, where $\alpha$ is the middle point at which the function moves from 1 to 0 (0.25 in the illustration) and $\beta$ controls how *steep* is that transition (200 in the illustration).

What I don't like about my current solution is that I need to set $\beta$ to a *high* arbitrary number to get a steep transition, which is what I need for my application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**Edit**: The function and its derivative need to be continuous.

Comment: What about Sigmoid?

Comment: Thanks @VezenBU. Do you have a specific sigmod function in mind? Cheers.

Comment: "Straightforward" depends on whatever your "application" is. If you're coding, for example, if(x>3) then(y=2) else(y=3), would be straightforward. Can you provide a bit more context? Also, a sigmoid function is what you have just replace the letters inside the parenthesis with $e$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBlumberg. I'm using this function within a Dynamic Programming problem. The Value Function needs to be concave and differentiable. I need this function to be continuous and differentiable. By "straightforward", I mean I would like to get rid of the $\beta$ parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\varphi(x)=e^{-1/t}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.  Now let
$$\psi(x)=\frac{\varphi(x)}{\varphi(x)+\varphi(1-x)}.$$
We have: $\psi(x)= 0$ for $x\le0$, $\psi(x)= 1$ for $x\ge1$.  Now adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I might be missing something because when I plot I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMDQx.png) (instead of $1-x$. I have $\alpha - x$).

Answer (score 0):

The hyperbolic tangent $\tanh$ is one typical function used for this kind of pseudo-step function. I could get something like your graph with
$$
\frac12(1-\tanh(200(x-0.25)).
$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1%2F2%281-tanh+%28200%28x-0.25%29%29%29+from+0+to+0.5)

[image]

There are some other candidate functions at [the Wikipedia article on sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the other sigmoid functions mentioned in the Wikipedia article. I find the function you propose is not simpler than mine. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, no other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind discontinuity: $\frac{\mathrm{sgn}(\alpha-x)+1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks! I might need to take a derivative, and I need that derivative to be continuous.